# How to set AutoLayout Constraints for this design

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode7.3

I am trying to create a basic design as shown in the image below

[image]

This image is how I want my GUI. I have a background image and three buttons. How can I set the constarints for these buttons to be same on every screen size ? I am having problem because I do not want to fox the width of button I want them to be adjustable according to screen size.
How can I do that please help.

Comment: you can use equal width constraints with multiplier to adjust its width according to screensize

Comment: I do know how to do it programticaal but. Is not possible without writing any code ? suing interface builder only ?

Comment: it is without coding ... in storyboard with constraints

Comment: You could use an UIStackView for this also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide Leading space , top space, trailling space and hight for your button after that if will adjust width for any particular screen.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. Leading and Trailing constraints are the key constraints to adjustable width. Height and vertical spacing set accordingly,

[image]

Comment: can you please share screenshot with some sample views ?